# Accessing an ipv6 NAT64 connection on my iPad, broadcast from Mac

Tags: ipad, wifi, internet-sharing, ipv6

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on how to setup an ipv6 wi-fi connection, so I can test my app:

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

If I don't tick the "**Created NAT64 Network**", it works fine (and I can connect and use the wi-fi connection from my iPad). However, as soon as I tick that box I don't get anything (says "*No Internet Connection*" when trying to access from the iPad)

Setting it up with this works fine, but its on an ipv4 address:

[image]

Enabling NAT64 works, and shows the connection on the iPad, BUT there is no connection:

[image]

[image]

Here are the software versions of my iPad:

[image]

The Mac is running on 10.12.1, so should be a high enough version to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same a couple of days ago to control my app for ipv6 (even if I didn’t need to do so), you should also switch off WiFi on you router / modem and you need to switch on the airplane mode on you iPad. 
Mind that in the latest version of Xcode your app must be compiled for ipv6 automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wouldn't airplane mode stop wifi on the iPad though?

Comment: It switches WiFi off for the moment as a default instruction, but if you switch on WiFi you will have it with airplane mode

Comment: @Kaleri - ah ok. I tried that, but still no joy. I've also tried disabling the wifi on the router (I'm hard-wired into the Mac anyway). I tried to update my version of XCode to the latest, but it needed the latest version of iOS, and for some reason mine won't update ( https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79129 ). I'm struggling to think of what else to try :/

Comment: Why do you need ipv6 anyway? May you’ve done the same my mistake

Comment: Applie replied with: `We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 11.1.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

- Once we launch the app, the activity indicator spins indefinitely and we are not able to enter the app. ` . The problem is that the ipv4 devices it works fine on, so I'm thinking it must be an ipv6 issue (thus trying to get it going)

Comment: Are you using CloudKit in your app? If yes, have you deployed to production your container?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I eventually found out the problem. I'm using Phonegap Build, and the newer version now uses the `gap://` protocol in the apps. This was causing the security to fail. So after all that fun and games, it turns out I didn't even need to look at the ipv6 stuff. The app is submitted and accepted now :) Thanks for your help though!